# How do I neglect suppressed terms in an expression?

Tags: series-expansion

I have an expression along the lines of

`expression = a^2 + a + b^2 + a*b`

Each variable has a big-O notation scaling, e.g. `a` ~ O(x^2) and `b` ~ O(x) for x<<1.  I want to write a function that neglects the terms that are suppressed by higher powers of x, and keeps only the leading order O(x^2) terms, `a + b^2`.

Performing a Taylor series in `a` using

`Series[expression,{a,0,1}]`

serves to get rid of the `a^2` term, but keeps the `a*b` term because it is linear in `a`, even though it is actually O(x^3).

Is there a way I can assign big-O scaling to `a` and `b` without actually assigning those variables specific values, so that I can suppress the terms using `expression + O[x^3]`?  Or is there a better way to achieve the desired output?

Comment: `(Series[expression /. {a -> a*t^2, b -> b*t}, {t, 0, 2}] // 
   Normal) /. t -> 1` evaluates to `a + b^2`